# What is the difference between possible hrtimer initializations?

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel

According to the hrtimer.h, HRTIMER_MODE_ABS means time value is absolute whereas HRTIMER_MODE_REL means time value is relative to now.

When used in the context of hrtimer_init, CLOCK_MONOTONIC or CLOCK_REALTIME can be also be chosen. This means that hrtimers can be initialized in several ways such as below.

```
hrtimer_init(&timer, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_ABS);
hrtimer_init(&timer, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);

hrtimer_init(&timer, CLOCK_REALTIME, HRTIMER_MODE_ABS);
hrtimer_init(&timer, CLOCK_REALTIME, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
```

Upon inspection of hrtimer.c, the 4th intialization has no effect because the clock_id is set back to CLOCK_MONOTONIC if mode is not HRTIMER_MODE_ABS upon initialization.

```
if (clock_id == CLOCK_REALTIME && mode != HRTIMER_MODE_ABS)
        clock_id = CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
```

So that leaves us with 3 possible behaviours. Now I understand the CLOCK_REALTIME is affected by system time therefore might be discontinuous, whereas CLOCK_MONOTONIC is the opposite (i.e. it is always ticking forward).

The following is my understanding of the possible behaviours, but they seem way too similar and I am unsure which to choose.

1) `hrtimer_init(&timer, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_ABS);`

The clock is continuous and time always expires after an absolute time of N. Changes in system time does not affect the clock therefore it does not affect expiry time.

2) `hrtimer_init(&timer, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);`

The clock is continuous and time expires N time from now. Changes in system time does not affect the clock therefore it does not affect expiry time from 'now'.

3) `hrtimer_init(&timer, CLOCK_REALTIME, HRTIMER_MODE_ABS);`

The clock can be set but any changes to system clock still does not affect expiry, because the timer is set to expire at an absolute time of N.

I realized my interpretation could be wrong because the behaviours all look similar. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: In the third case (`hrtimer_init(&timer, CLOCK_REALTIME, HRTIMER_MODE_ABS);`), irregular adjustments to the system clock after starting the timer affect the amount of real time (measured in CPU cycles or whatever) passed until the timer expires.

Comment: Does that mean the absolute time as "seen" by the hrtimer is unchanged since it is blind to the discontinuity? Is that what absolute expiry means?

Comment: I think most of the clock sources are subject to minor adjustments, but some of them, such as `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` can only advance forwards. `CLOCK_REALTIME` can go jump backwards due to the system (wall-clock) time being changed by the system administrator or some start-up script.

Comment: If so, whats the practical difference between `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` with `HRTIMER_MODE_ABS` and `HRTIMER_MODE_REL`?

Answer (score 0):

from [linux/hrtimer.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1a3b1bba7c7a5eb8a11513cf88427cb9d77bc60a/include/linux/hrtimer.h#L28)

> Mode arguments of xxx_hrtimer functions:
>
> HRTIMER_MODE_ABS      - Time value is absolute
> HRTIMER_MODE_REL      - Time value is relative to now

HRTIME_MODE_ABS means your time argument is absolute, e.g. "time out at 10:00 AM" while HRTIME_MODE_REL means your argument is relative, e.g. "time out 3min from now".

#### Examples:

Time out in 5ms from now:

```
hrtimer_start(&dev->poll_hrt, ms_to_ktime(5), HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
```

Time out in 5ms from last timeout:

```
hrtimer_start(&dev->poll_hrt, last_timeout + ms_to_ktime(5), HRTIMER_MODE_ABS);
```

Using CLOCK_REALTIME, which as you noted could change, with a relative value doesn't make sense, since a clock change will affect your timeout duration. Using CLOCK_REALTIME with an absolute value might make sense if you want something to occur at a specific time of day, but I think those situations are rare (indeed, a quick search of the kernel shows the overwhelming majority of the time CLOCK_MONOTONIC is used)